# Is it okay to not use batchnorm and relu before global average pooling?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I have built and experiment with a small network by batchnorm-relu-conv rather than conv-batchnorm-relu as suggested by DenseNet(2017). In denseNet, Before global average pooling layer, there are batchnorm and relu added below the last conv layer.

What would happen if i removed batchnorm and relu from here?

In my experiments, contrary to my expectations, the network showed higher accuracy when removing batchnorm and relu.

Can someone explain this result?